# Spammers can send me mail from my own email address with a different IP

Tags: exchange-2010, spam

I have checked everything and, normally, my server blocks all spam messages, but not this one. It does not originate from our servers but they get relayed to our company with our username. It looks like I am sending these emails to myself :D

I am using Exchange Server 2010. I have reviewed all spf records and dmarc. Everything seems OK on my end. I need help to stop these emails from getting to my users.

Here is the header of incoming spam mail:

```
> Received: from crt21.co.jp (60.43.215.250) by server.xxxxx.local 
> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id x.x.x.x; Tue, 5
> Feb  2019 09:05:56 +0300 
> Received: from [84-241-41-230.shatel.ir]
> (unknown [84.241.41.230]) (using  TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
> (256/256 bits))   (Client did not present  a certificate) by crt21.co.jp
> (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 0568913F380A2   for  <myname@mydomain.com>;
> Tue,  5 Feb 2019 15:02:04 +0900 (JST) 
> From: <myname@mydomain.com>
> Date: Tue, 5 Feb 2019 07:02:07 +0100 
> List-Unsubscribe:<mailto:C10155B2CC1F1C4E8D31E99D8211F1@unsubscribe.crt21.co.jp>,
> X-Priority: 1 (Highest) 
> X-Mailer: Duesfatyjz 8 
> Subject: This account has been hacked! Change your password right now!
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Type: text/plain;
> charset="UTF-8" X-CSA-Complaints: whitelistcomplaints@crt21.co.jp
> List-Help: contact@crt21.co.jp 
> Message-ID:<3qngvtqdrb8h$0wg3v672$xnrd6nmz$@crt21.co.jp> 
> X-Sender:<satoshi@crt21.co.jp> 
> X-Abuse-Reports-To: <abuse@crt21.co.jp> 
> To:<myname@mydomain.com> Errors-To: noreply@crt21.co.jp 
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.16) 
> Gecko/20101125 Thunderbird/3.0.11 MIME-Version: 1.0 
> Return-Path:satoshi@crt21.co.jp 
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: server.xxxxxxx.local
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PRD: mydomain.com
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SenderIdResult: SoftFail 
> Received-SPF:SoftFail (server.xxxxxxx.local: domain of transitioning 
> myname@mydomain.com discourages use of 60.43.215.250 as  permitted
> sender) 
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
> X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: 
> DV:3.3.5705.600;SID:SenderIDStatus SoftFail;OrigIP:60.43.215.250
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. That's how electronic mail was designed. *From* can be anything but the *Envelope From* (never shown in Header) must match the SPF-Records.

Comment: I know but while the origin of the mail does not match the spf , shouldn't it be refused ? My server normally drop spam mail by checking their ptr record but this one could pass.

Answer (score 0):

Did these emails have any thing in common, such as same subject? If yes, you could set transport rule to block such message.

Please check if your Exchange servers are an open relay. There is a very simple command that you can run from the Exchange Management Shell to close this down.

The command is:

Get-ReceiveConnector “YourReceiveConnectorName” | Remove-ADPermission -User “NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON” -ExtendedRights “ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient”

To prevent anonymous senders from sending mail using your domain(s), we need to remove the ms-exch-smtp-accept-authoritative-domain-sender permission assigned to them.

Use the following command to remove the ms-exch-smtp-accept-authoritative-domain-sender permission from NT Authority\Anonymous Logon on internet-facing Receive Connector(s):

Get-ReceiveConnector “My Internet ReceiveConnector” | Get-ADPermission -user “NT AUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon” | where {$_.ExtendedRights -like “ms-exch-smtp-accept-authoritative-domain-sender”} | Remove-ADPermission

Comment: thanks I just found that there is 3 RecieveConnectors and 2 of them which are for local users have anonymous permissions. I removed them and I hope we wont get such emails anymore. Thanks.

Comment: now anyone whom sent me mail get this error : 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Comment: Only remove for internet-facing Receive Connector.

Comment: The one with the internet-facing already has unchecked for anonymous logon.

Comment: Did the spam messages reduce ?

Comment: Spam messages mostly blocked . However there is a specific mail coming from a lamer whom seems sending from my server to me by my mail address and he is looking for some bitcoins. normally this mail should also be marked as spam and users should not see that. Cause the origin of mail is from a different ip of exchange server's ip. but still exist coming time to time

Comment: You could create a transport rule to delete this kind of message with bitcoins individually.